# How do I retrieve a node in Xcode Scenekit if it's out of scope?

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, nodename

Here is the Scenekit code instead of sprite kit. So i'm trying to access the box within the touches began method using it's name which in this case is "box" but it's out of scope and I try'd using the same technique like spritekit but it's not the same.

```
   //BOX
    SCNBox *boxGeometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:10
                                        height:10
                                        length:10
                                 chamferRadius:0.3];
    SCNNode *box = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:boxGeometry];
    box.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 0);
    boxGeometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wood.png"];
    boxGeometry.firstMaterial.specular.contents = [UIColor whiteColor];
    boxGeometry.firstMaterial.shininess = 10.0;
    box.name = @"box";
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:box];




-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];


    if (location.x > 160) {
    }
    else{
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

call `-childNodeWithName:recursively:` on the scene's `rootNode`.

Comment: nothing happens could you give an example in my code please ?

Comment: Could you show me the line of code to access it then ?

Comment: It won't let me show you because it's too many characters in the comment box

Comment: doesn't `[scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"box" recursively:YES]` work ?`

Comment: within the viewdidload method, yes. Not in the touchesbegan method though?

Comment: then you should verify that `scene` is not `nil`, and then print its child nodes and verify that `box` is still there.

Comment: again... can you provide an example ?

Comment: I gave you one and it couldn't be simpler. Something must has changed in your scene. Set a breakpoint in `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` and verify that `scene` is not `nil` and that all its child nodes are still there.

Comment: still nothing happens